# Json returns as undefined, replace undefined with text

Tags: javascript, json

first time dealing with json, so not really sure..
when a user online the api returns with

```
user example
live    true
viewers 22
passwordProtected   false
banned  false
```

but when im offline "viewers" gets removed.
so data.viewers comes back as undefined, how can i change it to e.g offline?

script:

```
<script>
$.getJSON('https://example.com/api/example', function(data) {

    var text = `${data.viewers}`


    $(".mypanel").html(text);
});

</script>
```

Comment: `data.viewers || "offline"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) function.

```
var text = "offline";
if(data.hasOwnProperty('viewers'){
  text = data.viewers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check for undefined like so:

```
var text = "offline";
if (data.length && data.viewers !== undefined) {
    var text = data.viewers;
}
```

or with a ternary operator:

```
var text = (data.viewers !== undefined) ? data.viewers : "offline";
```

Ps. no need for the interpolation when saving a variable. ie `${data.viewers}`
This is used when adding variables to a string value like html.

Comment: The template literal may still be useful. It causes `data.viewers` to be coerced to a string and assign that to `text`. If `text` was `false`, `$(".mypanel").html(text);` would cause `$(".mypanel")` to be empty. A string would work normally.

Comment: Coercing the data to a string this way is useful. Thanks for the tip, but I'm not sure sending `false` as a string to the browser is generally what is wanted here. Either way, the `||` statement from your comment above is the cleanest.